# Javascript Service workers is it possible to just 1 line cache any .js .css that if fetched?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, worker

I'm checking tutorials about javascript workers and stuff for PWA (Progressive Web App)...

I only see this

```
const assets = [
  '/',
  '/blabla.js',
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) { 
    evt.waitUntil(
        caches.open('static').then((cache) => {
            cache.addAll(assets);
        })
    );
});
```

For external js like this one https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js it's not specifically written if it would work or not...

in the `assets` can a pattern like this works ?

`/(.js|.css|.png|.jpg|.json|.html)/`

Or would I need stars

`/(*.js|*.css|*.png|*.jpg|*.json|*.html)/`

there is a lack about this on documentations I encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Hi found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChXgikdQJR8

in the `self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {` add stuff like  `return cacheRes || fetch(evt.request).then(fetchRes => {`

see the full .js there

https://github.com/iamshaunjp/pwa-tutorial/blob/lesson-29/public/sw.js